Create a X.509 Certificate with Authority Key Identifier extension in C# using CERTEnroll.dll
for a legacy .NET Framework application I need to create a self-signed certificate using CERTENROLLLib (i.e. CERTEnroll.dll from the Windows SDK).
A basic certificate can be successfully created using this method.
As a new feature this certicicate must contain an Authority Key Identifier extension. This is added to the working certificate request:
var dn = new CX500DistinguishedName();
dn.Encode("CN=" + certificate.SubjectName);

var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
var serialNumberBytes = new byte[SerialNumberLengthMin];
rng.GetBytes(serialNumberBytes);

// Only positive numbers are allowed
serialNumberBytes[serialNumberBytes.Length - 1] &= 0x7f;

// Convert it to a hex string in little endian
var serialNumber = GetHexString(serialNumberBytes, true);

var certificateRequest = new CX509CertificateRequestCertificate();

CX509ExtensionAuthorityKeyIdentifier aki = new CX509ExtensionAuthorityKeyIdentifierClass();
aki.InitializeEncode(EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_HEX, CreateAuthorityKeyIdentifier(dn.Name, serialNumberBytes));
certificateRequest.X509Extensions.Add((CX509Extension)aki);

The method CreateAuthorityKeyIdentifier uses AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER) to generate a string that is converted to a big endian hex string.
private static string CreateAuthorityKeyIdentifier(string issuer, byte[] serialNumber)
{
  var keyId = "2.5.29.35";
  
  var writer = new AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER);
  writer.PushSequence();

  var keyIdTag = new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 0);
  writer.WriteOctetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyId), keyIdTag);
 
  var issuerNameTag = new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 1);
  writer.PushSequence(issuerNameTag);
  var directoryNameTag = new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 4, true);
  writer.PushSetOf(directoryNameTag);
  writer.WriteEncodedValue((new X500DistinguishedName(issuer)).RawData);
  writer.PopSetOf(directoryNameTag);
  writer.PopSequence(issuerNameTag);

  var issuerSerialTag = new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 2);
  var issuerSerial = new BigInteger(serialNumber);
  writer.WriteInteger(issuerSerial, issuerSerialTag);

  writer.PopSequence();

  return GetHexString(writer.Encode());
}

After creating an enrollment and calling CX509Enrollment.CreatePFX this throws an exception with error code CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::CreatePFX: Invalid Signature. 0x80090006 (-2146893818 NTE_BAD_SIGNATURE).
The CX509Enrollment.InstallResponse is called before and does not throw an exception.
I'm at a loss solving the cause of the exception.
The certificate is correctly created with other extensions.
Sadly the authority key identifier is needed by the used library to accept this certificate.

Are you sure it's not InitializeDecode that you need instead?

Also how can you pass the serialNumber of the self-signed certificate if you haven't created it yet? Where does serialNumberBytes actually come from?

@Charlieface I added the generation of the serialNumber and serialNumberBytes, but they are correctly created and work with the certificate request if no AuthorityKeyIdentifier extension is added.
Honestly, I didn't try InitializeDecode yet, that might be a good idea!
Is there any good documentation available for this? MSDN/MS Learn is not very helpful...

"and work with the certificate request if no AuthorityKeyIdentifier extension is added" but then you don't seem to be using it anywhere. It's supposed to be derived from the private key, not a random string of bytes. No not much in the way of clear docs that I can see. To be honest, I still don't get why you aren't using built-in .NET stuff, you can just install the Nuget package for .NET Framework https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

I gave InitializeDecode a try, resulted in the same exception:
'CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::CreatePFX: Invalid Signature. 0x80090006 (-2146893818 NTE_BAD_SIGNATURE)'

@Charlieface:
Thanks for your response.
If you can show me a way to use System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates to generate a self-signed certificate using .NET Framework 4.6.1, I'd be delighted. I don't think that's possible in that old version.
What should be derived from the private key? The AuthorityKeyIdentifier?
This is not the complete code for the whole generation of the certificate! It's just the gist of it - everything works without using the AKI extension - I need to find the bug in its generation.
Thanks for your help!

Did you use the Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates/#supportedframeworks-body-tab on a side note it's unusual to be targetting 4.6.1, because all supported systems should already be on 4.8. And 4.6.1 is already EOL.
